# Shall we capitalize the word after colon?

Tags: capitalization

Shall we capitalize the word after colon?

For example:

> The question is: S/shall we capitalize "s" in "shall"?

Another example, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/91024/1005

> For example:
>
> - E/every marginal distribution of a multivariate normal distribution must be a univariate normal distribution.
> - S/so it is for the multinomial distribution (which is the multivariate generalization of binomial distribution).
> - S/so it is for Dirichlet distribution (which is the multivariate generalization of beta distribution)
> - N/not sure  for multivariate t distribution.

(In other words, should each of those individual bullets be capitalized, or not?)

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what follows the colon.

- **Is it a list of items?** *Leave the first item in lower case*.
- **Is it more than one sentence?** *Capitalize all of them*.
- **Is it one sentence?** *It's your option*. I'm more prone to use upper-case depending if I want a sharper demarcation between what precedes and follows the colon, and a lower case if I want a smoother flow.

This pretty much echoes the guidance given by sites such as [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/colons?page=2), [CCCF](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/colon.htm), [GrammarBook](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/commas/capitalization-with-colons/), [UNC Writing Center](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/semi-colons-colons-and-dashes/).

Examples:

> - **These three things remain: faith, hope, and love.** [list]
> - **Everybody wanted to know: What would happen next? Would Batman be saved?** [two sentences]
> - **All of the clues led to one conclusion: The butler was the one who did it.** [single sentence, upper case]
> - **The librarian warned the rowdy students: excessive noise would not be tolerated.** [single sentence, lower case]

I like the practical guidance one person wrote at the [Q-and-A site](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Capitalization/faq0019.html) for the *Chicago Manual of Style*:

> Rules can’t cover every instance. Don’t waste time overthinking: if it’s that hard to determine, it probably doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, a list such as this punctuated as one sentence, despite the bullet points. This means that every point starts with a lowercase letter, and every line finishes with a comma / semicolon, apart from the final line, which ends with a full stop (or *period*, as Americans would say).

When writing less formally, or in general, you would forget the layout described above, and every point would start with a capital, and every line would finish with a full stop (*period*, as Americans would say).

I would say that it mostly comes down to preference. It is likely there is a rule defining how such lists should be formatted, but very few people still consider them relevant. There is no longer a 'right' or 'wrong' way, and it is more likely that the capitalisation *would* happen.

Comment: What about the lines before the final line are questions? Shall them be ended with a question mark instead of a semicolon, and shall the first letter of the next line be capitalized?

Comment: If the statement with the bullet list is a question, all the point would end with a semicolon, and, correct, the final line would end with a question mark.